# Deflation of eigenvalue

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods

Could you explain to me the deflation?

For example if we have the matrix  $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -0.5 & -1.5\\ -15 & -2.5 & 4.5\\ -15 & -4.5 & 2.5\end{pmatrix}$ how do we apply the deflation of the eigenvalue $\lambda_1=4$ ?

$$$$

**EDIT :**

I have done the following :

We have the eigenvalue $\lambda_1=4$. The corresponding eigenvector is : $v_1=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\ 3 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$, right?

Since $v_1$ does not have $1$ as the component of largest modulus, we multiply  $v_1$ by a permutation matrix $P$ which interchanges the largest element and the first element: We interchange rows $1$ and $2$ of $A$ : $v_1'=\begin{pmatrix}3 \\-1\\  1\end{pmatrix}$
$$\begin{pmatrix}-15 & -2.5 & 4.5\\1 & -0.5 & -1.5\\  -15 & -4.5 & 2.5\end{pmatrix}$$
We want to transform the vector into the vector $e_1$, so we divide the first row by $3$, add it to the second row and subtract it from the third row : $v_1''=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\0\\  0\end{pmatrix}$
$$\begin{pmatrix}-5 & -5/6 & 1.5\\-4 & -4/3 & 0\\  -10 & -11/3 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$ Since we have interchanged the rows $1$ and $2$, now we have to interchange the columns $1$ and $2$ and so we get the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} -5/6 & -5 &1.5\\-4/3 & -4 & 0\\   -11/3 & -10 &1\end{pmatrix}$$ Then $\lambda_1=4$ should be an eigenvalue of this matrix with $e_1$ the corresponding eigenvector, but this is not like that. What am I doing wrong?

Is the deflated matrix equal to $$\begin{pmatrix} -4 & 0\\   -10 &1\end{pmatrix}$$ ?

Comment: What do you know about deflation, and what have you attempted ?

Comment: You are not at all a newcomer. Say at least where you are stumped...

Comment: Please check my edited question above! Do you have an idea? @JeanMarie

Comment: You applied row operations to transform $v_1'$ into $v_1''=e_1$ and you applied the same operations to the matrix on the left. Now you still have to apply the inverse of those row operations on the right to find the matrix with $e_1$ as eigenvector. This only affects the left column though. So the sub matrix is not affected and you do have the correct deflated matrix.

Comment: Note that if we multiply the matrix you've found with $v_1'=\begin{pmatrix}3\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix}$ that we indeed find $\lambda_1 e_1=\begin{pmatrix}4\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $v_1=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\3\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

Let $P$ be the permutation matrix that swaps the first 2 elements.
Then $Pv_1=v_1'=\begin{pmatrix}3\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix}$ has the element with the largest magnitude first.

Let $R$ be the matrix of row operations that transforms $v_1'$ into $e_1$. That is $Rv_1'=e_1$.

Then $R=\begin{pmatrix}1/3\\1/3 & 1\\-1/3 &&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Let $B=RPAP^{-1}R^{-1}$. Then $B$ is *similar* to $A$ and:
$$Be_1=RPAP^{-1}R^{-1}e_1=RPAP^{-1}v_1'=RPAv_1=RP\lambda_1 v_1=\lambda_1Rv_1'=\lambda_1e_1$$
So $B$ has $\lambda_1$ as eigenvalue with eigenvector $e_1$.

You have found $RPAP^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} -5/6 & -5 &1.5\\-4/3 & -4 & 0\\   -11/3 & -10 &1\end{pmatrix}$. We can verify that if we multiply it with $v_1'$ we find $\lambda_1 e_1$.

If we multiply it on the right with $R^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}3\\-1&1\\1&&1\end{pmatrix}$ then we find $B=\begin{pmatrix}4&-5&3/2\\&-4&0\\&-10&1\end{pmatrix}$.

So $B$ has indeed $e_1$ as an eigenvector for $\lambda_1=4$.

The resulting deflated matrix is $B_1=\begin{pmatrix}-4&0\\-10&1\end{pmatrix}$, which we already had in $RPAP^{-1}$ since $R^{-1}$ affected only the leftmost column. This matches your findings.

We can verify that $B_1$ has indeed the same remaining eigenvalues $-4$ and $1$ as $A$, which are on its diagonal since $B_1$ is a triangular matrix.

Comment: I see! Then could we apply one more deflation of one of the eigenvalues for example for $\lambda=-4$ and apply that on $B_1$ and then the deflated matrix must be a $1\times 1$ matrix with the element $1$, right?

Comment: Correct @MaryStar.

Comment: Deflation of the eigenvalue $-4$ : 

We have the eigenvalue $\lambda_2=-4$ of the matrix $B_1$ and the corresponding eigenvector is $v_2=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 2\end{pmatrix}$. 

Since $v_2$ has not the greatest element in the first place, we multiply $v_2$ by a permutation matrix $P$ that interchanges the rows $1$ and $2$. 

Then $Pv_2=v_2'=\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\end{pmatrix}$ has the greatest element in the first place.

Comment: Now we want to transform this vector into $e_1$, so we divide the first row by $2$ and subtract the first row by the second row. 

Let $R$ be the matrix with the row operations, then $Rv_2'=e_1$.

We have the matrix $R=\begin{pmatrix}1/2 & 0   \\-1/2  &1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Let $B=RPB_1P^{-1}R^{-1}$. 

Then we have that $B=\begin{pmatrix}1/2 & 0   \\-1/2  &1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0& 1\\ 1& 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-4&0\\-10&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0& 1\\ 1& 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0   \\1/2  &1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-3/2 & -5\\ -1/2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Your $R^{-1}$ is not correct @MaryStar.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right!! Thank you very much!!! :-)

Comment: Do you maybe have also an idea at my other question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4603403/householder-reduction-to-hessenberg-form ?

Comment: You got a comment that seems to address your question @MaryStar. Does it?

Comment: Yes! Thank you nevertheless!! :-)

Answer (score 5):

$\require{cancel}$

In fact, the method I know under the name "deflation" does not use at all permutation matrices.

Let us say first that matrix

$$A = \pmatrix{1&-0.5&-1.5\\-15&-2.5&4.5\\-15&-4.5&2.5}$$

has eigenvalues $\{-4,4,1\}$.

You just need to find 3 "ingredients" :

- "the" (or "one of the") eigenvalue(s) $\lambda$ with largest modulus. In your case, indeed $\lambda = 4$ (you could have chosen $\lambda = -4$),
- a right eigenvector associated with this $\lambda$, here $R=\pmatrix{-1\\3\\1}$ indeed,
- a left eigenvector associated with $\lambda$, which is an ordinary eigenvector of the transpose matrix $A^T$ ; I have obtained:  $L=\pmatrix{5\\1\\-2}$.

for applying the following deflation "recipe" :

$$A_1:=A-\tfrac{\lambda}{R^TL}RL^T$$

Giving the numerical answer:

$$A_1=\pmatrix{-4&-1.5&0.5\\0&0.5&-1.5\\-10&-3.5&0.5}$$

with eigenvalues $\{-4,0,1\}$ as awaited.

Please note that, in the formula above,  $RL^T$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix, whereas $R^TL$ is a number, the dot product of vectors $R$ and $L$.

**Remark :** The deflated matrix (as I "understand" it) remains a $3 \times 3$. It doesn't become a $2 \times 2$ matrix.

**Sanity check :** Let us establish that vector $R$ has become an eigenvector of $A_1$ with eigenvalue $0$ :

$$A_1R=(A-\tfrac{\lambda}{R^TL}RL^T)R=AR-\tfrac{\lambda}{R^TL}R(L^TR)$$

$$A_1R=\lambda R - \tfrac{\lambda}{\cancel{R^TL}}R(\cancel{L^TR})=0$$

(the cancellation takes place because the dot product is commutative)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! :-)