# Householder reduction to Hessenberg form

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods

I want to transform the matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 15 & -6 & 0 \\ 1 & 7 & 3 & 12 \\ 2 & -7 & -3 & 0 \\ 2 & -28 & 15 & 3\end{pmatrix}$$ using Householder-Transformation to an upper Hessenberg form.

$$$$

I have done the following :

Do we consider the first column of $A$ without the first row ?

We consider $a=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 2\\ 2\end{pmatrix}$.

The Householder Matrix is $$H_1=I-2uu^T$$ with $u:=\frac{a_1-\alpha\cdot e_1}{\|a_1-\alpha\cdot e_1\|_2}$ and $\alpha=\pm \|a_1\|_2=\pm \sqrt{9}=\pm 3$.

We have that $\|a_1-\alpha\cdot e_1\|_2=\begin{cases}\left \|\begin{pmatrix}1-3\\ 2\\ 2\end{pmatrix}\right \|_2=\left \|\begin{pmatrix}-2\\ 2\\ 2\end{pmatrix}\right \|_2=\sqrt{12}\\ \left \|\begin{pmatrix}1+3\\ 2\\ 2\end{pmatrix}\right \|_2=\left \|\begin{pmatrix}4\\ 2\\ 2\end{pmatrix}\right \|_2=\sqrt{24}\end{cases}$.

So when $\alpha=-3$ the norm is greater. So we get $u:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{24}}\begin{pmatrix}4\\ 2\\ 2\end{pmatrix}$.

Therefore we get $$H_1=I-2uu^T=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}-2\frac{1}{24}\begin{pmatrix}4\\ 2\\ 2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}4& 2& 2\end{pmatrix}\\ =\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0  \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}-\frac{1}{12}\begin{pmatrix}16 & 8 & 8 \\ 8 & 4 & 4 \\ 8 & 4 & 4\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-1/3 &  -2/3 &  -2/3 \\ -2/3 &  2/3 &  -1/3\\ -2/3 & -1/3 & 2/3\end{pmatrix}$$

So we have the matrix $$P_1=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1/3 &  -2/3 &  -2/3 \\ 0 & -2/3 &  2/3 &  -1/3\\ 0 & -2/3 & -1/3 & 2/3\end{pmatrix}$$
Then we get $$P_1AP_1^{-1}\\ =\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1/3 &  -2/3 &  -2/3 \\ 0 & -2/3 &  2/3 &  -1/3\\ 0 & -2/3 & -1/3 & 2/3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 15 & -6 & 0 \\ 1 & 7 & 3 & 12 \\ 2 & -7 & -3 & 0 \\ 2 & -28 & 15 & 3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 &  0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1/3 & -2/3 & -2/3 \\ 0 &  -2/3 & 2/3 & -1/3\\ 0 & -2/3 & -1/3 & 2/3\end{pmatrix}$$ and we apply again the above for the second column without the first two rows.

Is that correct so far?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct. The point of th Householder reflectors is that you never need to compute the full matrix and matrix-matrix products. You can compute the transformed matrix just from $Av$, $v^TA$ and $v^TAv$.